# How to update a table when its specified date is today in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp, auto-update

I have a table in my database that has a closing date column that was an input from a user. Now I want to update a column status when the closing date is today..
Are there any suggestions on how can I do this?

Comment: You kinda said what needs to be done. What part is the issue and what have you tried?

Comment: I might need rephrase it.. For  example the closing date is on July 7. And I need to update the column status to closed when the date is on July 7 with no user action (i.e INSERT or UPDATE to the column)

Comment: You run a scheduled task that does it on required intervals and updates it. How that is done depends on the system it's running on.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Should we do it in the logic? Can it be done in mysql?

Comment: You need an external task scheduler to run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for answers I found out there you can CREATE AN EVENT in MySQL. 
this link should help http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/.

Answer (score 0):

If your have running your database on an server that is allways running, try to use crontab(linux) or something equal.

Crontab is a deamon that runs some commands for you at specified date. I myself use crontab in combination with php scripts to reset some stuff in by mysql database.

Where is your database running ? - Maybee this would helf to answer.

Ask if you wanna know mor about this .

Gordon